# Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">   </canvas>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var currentx;
var currenty;
currentx=0;
currenty=200;

MoveRight();
```

I have functions that should update the canvas element and the global variables but they are not working. For instance my MoveRight function :

```
function MoveRight()
{

ctx.moveTo(currentx,currenty);
ctx.lineTo(currentx+40,currenty);
currentx=currentx+40;

}
```

I want my MoveRight function to draw a horizontal line every time it is called and update the global variables (currentx and currenty).

Comment: canvas is inside the html tags and the functions are inside the <script>  </script>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to stroke your line!

`beginPath()` will start and remeber what to draw, then `stroke()` to draw it. You can then use `beginPath()` to clear the stroke memory so the same line isn't drawn again.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var currentx;
var currenty;
currentx=0;
currenty=200;

MoveRight();

function MoveRight()
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(currentx,currenty);
    ctx.lineTo(currentx+40,currenty);
    currentx=currentx+40;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<button onclick="MoveRight();">Move right!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

its just as @Dwadelfri says, I just wanted to say that you are doing the same operation two times

```
ctx.lineTo(currentx+40, currenty);
currentx = currentx + 40;
```

can be converted to

```
currentx += 40;
ctx.lineTo(currentx, currenty);
```

it's more readable and better quality this way